# Como pasar de String a un array de uint8_t en Arduino

Tags: c++, array, arduino, conversión-de-tipos

Tengo en mi programa de Arduino IDE un string que quiero convertir en una lista de uint8_t y no se bien como hacerlo. El string tendría este formato:

```
String str="0xAB, 0x39, 0x05, 0xD0, 0x7E, 0xD5, 0xB3, 0x70";
```

Bien, pues lo que quiero conseguir es un array de longitud 8, cada posición formada de un uint8_t con los valores de str. Tendría que quedar algo asi:

```
static const uint_8t PROGMEM array[8]={0xAB, 0x39, 0x05, 0xD0, 0x7E, 0xD5, 0xB3, 0x70};
```

Nunca he programado en Arduino y hacer estas conversiones me cuesta, espero que podáis ayudarme, gracias de antemano!

Comment: Arduino se programa en C/C++. El código que pides no depende de la plataforma.

Answer (score 0):

Solución: tienes que *escribirlo*

```
static const uint_8t PROGMEM array[8]={0xAB, 0x39, 0x05, 0xD0, 0x7E, 0xD5, 0xB3, 0x70};
```

El arreglo, amén de estático, está en PROGMEM, que residen en el Flash.

Arduino es una arquitectura Harvard, con memoria de código y memoria de datos físicamente separadas. Los programas no pueden alterar la memoria de código, y PROGMEM permite aprovechar esta memoria para almacenar constantes, evitando consumir preciosa RAM (sólo 2KB).

El único modo de tener lo que quieres es escribirlo directamente; por código no es posible.

Comment: Esa no es la solucion, he visto que gente ha conseguido lo que yo quiero, simplemente quiero cargar el valor desde un webServer que devuelve un string en una lista de uint8_t, se que se puede hacer pero no se como. Puedo poner un valor desde el inicio, y quitarle el "const" y cambiarlo despues desde una funcion, pero se tiene que poder cargar un string en la lista de uint8_t

Comment: Se puede convertir un string con sscanf, pero el resultado queda en RAM y tú lo quieres en PROGMEM. No puedes modificar PROGMEM desde dentro del programa, sólo durante el flasheado del código.

Answer (score 0):

La cuestión es que realmente tienes un String (que por cierto no te recomiendo que uses)
Es mas manejable como array de caracteres, que lo consigues con :

```
char *MiCharArray=str.c_str();  // Ya tenemos un puntero a tu String
```

una vez tenemos un puntero, con funciones del tipo: strtok los localizas y luego sscanf o strtol, lo conviertes.

En un bucle, vas buscando la "," (coma) extraes y conviertes ese texto Hexadecimal a un valor numérico (uint8_t). La conversión la puedes hacer facilmente con la función sscanf(), pese a que hay mas eficientes como strtol(TuTrozo, NULL, 16).

```
uint8_t Vector[8];
 
posicion = strtok(MiCharArray, ",");
if(posicion!=NULL)
   {
   // Hago lo que sea con el bloque
   MiVector[n]=(uint8_t)strtol(TuTrozo, NULL, 16);
   }
```

Espero haberte puesto en camino.

Saludos